# How to autosize the label in different pixel of devices?

Tags: xamarin.forms

As is we have may devices to fit and how to give the size property of a label?

if I give the Large it may not fit in the small device which has a small screen so that it can be not good displayed.

also the corner-radius property,I can give a corner-radius value which according to the width and height of a view.

for example:

```
<Image CornerRadius="15" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"></Image>
```

it is a circled image. but when the image's size changed the corner-radius property won't be changed according to the width or height of the image

how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case , if you want to let `CornerRadius` always equals half of its width (to make a circle control),you can use data binding and set its value in code behind .

### Solution 1 :

#### in xaml

```
<Frame CornerRadius="{Binding Radius}" Padding="0" WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" HeightRequest="{Binding Height}">
   <Image Source="xxx.png"/>
</Frame>
```

#### in code behind

```
public double Height { get; private set; }
public double Width{ get; private set; }
public double Radius{ get; private set; }
//...

Height = xxx;
Width = xxx;
Radius = Width / 2.0;
```

If you want to let controls have different size in different screen  , you can set the HeightRequest of controls as the percentage of screen (for example 10%) .

#### in Share Project App.xaml.cs

```
public static double ScreenWidth;
public static double ScreenHeight;
```

#### in Android MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Shell_Experimental", "Visual_Experimental", "CollectionView_Experimental");
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

   App.ScreenWidth = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density; 
   App.ScreenHeight =Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density; 

   LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

#### in iOS

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    //...
    App.ScreenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
    App.ScreenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
    //...
}
```

#### in Code Behind or ViewModel

```
Height = App.ScreenHeight/10.0;
Width = App.ScreenHeight/10.0;
Radius = Width / 2.0;
```

### Solution 2 :

You can add a reference to `Xamarin.Essentials` in your class:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
```

The following information is exposed through the API:

```
// Get Metrics
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

// Orientation (Landscape, Portrait, Square, Unknown)
var orientation = mainDisplayInfo.Orientation;

// Rotation (0, 90, 180, 270)
var rotation = mainDisplayInfo.Rotation;

// Width (in pixels)
var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;

// Height (in pixels)
var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;

// Screen density
var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
```

Comment: about the screenHeight there is a better solution.using the Xamarin.Esstentials.and you needn't to change code in the MainActivity.cs or AppDelegate.cs

Answer (score -1):

There is an excellent post here describing how to deal with this
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/styling-for-multiple-device-resolutions/